# Can a LocalVarSig have multiple constraint attributes?

Tags: cil, ilasm

In LocalVarSig syntax diagram the CustomMod and Constraint elements are in a loop, so this means there can be multiple Constraint elements. If there are more than one Constraint element, what is its semantics? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ECMA-335 §II.23.2.9, emphasis added:

> The Constraint item in Signatures **currently has only one possible**
>   **value**, ELEMENT_TYPE_PINNED (§II.23.1.16), which specifies that the
>   target type is pinned in the runtime heap, and will not be moved by
>   the actions of garbage collection.
>
> A Constraint can only be applied within a LocalVarSig (not a
>   FieldSig).

So `pinned` is the only possible constraint value, at least in the current version of CIL.

So, are multiple instances of `pinned` valid? It appears so. The assembler (ILasm) accepts multiple instances for a local variable:

```
.locals init (int32& pinned pinned pinned x)
```

If I assemble this and then disassemble it (ILdasm), the resulting IL retains the repeated `pinned` keyword. Peering into the assembly with [MdDumper](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-samples/tree/master/System.Reflection.Metadata/MdDumper) also shows the repeated `0x45` byte in the `StandAloneSig` table.

I haven't seen any verification differences with multiple `pinned` constraints, so I assume they are redundant, and equivalent to just having one `pinned`.